# FUSION LDV output to EPSG 32611

Tags: lidar, fusion

In `FUSION` the user can define the output coordinates, for example, in case of `GridSurfaceCreate` the user has the option to either set it to `NAD27 (1)` or `NAD83 (2)`. My question is, does the latest release of FUSION allow the option to use coordinates other than these two such as `EPSG:32611`?

```
C:\FUSION\GridSurfaceCreate64 /smooth:5 %PROC_DIR%\03_dtm\%PROJ%_dtm.dtm 1 M M 1 11 2 2 %PROC_DIR%\02_groundfilter\%PROJ%*.laz
```